# Space eaten in yasnippet template

Tags: yasnippet

**NOTE:** I use the symbol `␣` to represent the character `SPACE` (`U+0020`) for visibility.

I have a template like this:

```
${1:$$(yas-choose-value (with-current-buffer "foo-buf" (foo-get-name-list)))}␣[label="$1"];
```

When I pick an entry `"Foo"` from the list returned from `foo-get-name-list`, I expect to see an output line like

```
Foo␣[label="Foo"]
```

Instead, however, I get

```
Foo[label="Foo"]
```

How can I preserve that `SPACE` after `Foo` and before the `LEFT SQUARE BRACKET`?

Comment: Please choose only one forum, not both:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39375355/space-eaten-in-yasnippet-template

Comment: Sorry, @lawlist. After I posted on S/O, I remembered the existence of this forum and realized I should have posted here. I didn't see an obvious way to move the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `$$(yas-choose-value...` is not expanded before the indentation kicks in, so when yasnippet indents the snippet, the buffer text looks like: `␣[label=""];` and the space is removed by indenting.  You can disable indentation for a snippet by adding `# expand-env: ((yas-indent-line nil))` to the snippet.

I'm not sure yet whether to classify this as a yasnippet bug or not.